# AWS boto3 billing information

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm looking for a way to extract billing information using boto3. I've seen solutions using cost explorer but it's not a choice in my case. The information I want to extract is on Billing Dashboard > Bills. Is there a service on boto3 that facilitates this task?

Comment: Sadly, your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: Does this help? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html

Comment: @StephenTaylor I can't use CostExplorer, thank you for replyting anyways!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, using boto3. Using the CloudWatch client we can extract Billing metrics for any service we want:

1. [Monitor Estimated Charges with CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html)
2. [CloudWatch.Metric.get_statistics](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Metric.get_statistics)